# Compactness for the space of positive constant sectional curvarure and its conjugate points

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesic

I would like to prove the following statement (from *page 92 in Riemannian Geometry, An modern introduction* by Issac Chavel).

Suppose that $M$ is a Riemannian manifold with the constant sectional curvarure  $\kappa = 1$ and that there is a point $p\in M$, such that $\forall v \in cl(B(p,\pi)) \subset T_pM$, $\gamma_v(1)$ is well-defined (i.e., The exponential map is well-defined on that closed ball). Then $M$ is compact (hence complete) and the image of the sphere exp$_pS(p,\pi)$ is exactly 1 point.

If $M = \mathbb{S}^n$, then I can show this by direct computation. But without this, can anyone give me a hint or some material so that I can prove it ?.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact $M$ is locally isometric to the sphere?

Comment: Another way is to use Jacobi fields.

Comment: @Deane The local isometry to the sphere hasn't been introduced at this point, so maybe I have to show this by Jacobi fields.

Comment: You know the exact solutions to the Jacobi equation. That in turn tells you what happens to the exponential map along the bounds of the ball.

Comment: @Deane Yes, I know that points in the image of the sphere are conjugate points of $p \in M$, but I don't know how to proceed from here...

Comment: Forget the term conjugate point. Suppose you have a map, where you know its differential at every point in the domain. Suppose you’re given a submanifold of the domain and want to show its image is a single point. How do you use the differential to show this? My personal preference is to look at what happens along curves in the submanifold.

Comment: @Deane The differential is the zero map! So I can see why the image is a single point! But does it mean that $exp_p$ restricted on the closed ball is surjective?

Comment: If the manifold is connected, then yes. Some gratuitous advice: Despite the fact that I know well what the exponential map, sectional curvature, conjugate and cut points are, I find them hard to work with directly. I almost always translate whatever is being said into more concrete statements about families of geodesics (preferably 1-parameter family) and Jacobi fields.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for the advice. Here is my idea but right now I couldn't make it mathematically precise (any help is appreciated). Let $\gamma(t,v)$ be a family of geodesic from $p\in M$ where $v$ is a unit vector specifying the direction (parametrized by arclength). Then there exists some $t_0$ such that for $t_0 < t < \pi$, exp$_p(\gamma(t,\mathbb{S})$ is "a sphere around the conjugate point $q$" (here, $\mathbb{S}$ denotes the unit ball in $T_pM$). This means that the exponential map is onto near $q$. From here I can see the surjectivity.